# line-height value given as normal is different in different machine

Tags: html, firefox, css

I have given line-height as normal for table content. My table is a fixed size table (width and height both) with overflow hidden. So, rows are hidden in Firefox in some machines. Some laptops it shows all the rows while in some it crops the last row.

I checked in firebug there is a difference in line-height in both laptops.

I want to know, how does the line-height normal behave and should we use normal or integer values instead?

Comment: If you are giving the line-height in pixels.. then try using 'em'.. which is browser compatable

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard or defined behavior for line-heights. It depends on how that particular font-family, font-size, and line-height happens to be rendered by the browser on that operating system. 
To tackle the use in webkit based browsers, you can use :

```
 #link.menu > a {-webkit-padding-before: 1px;}
```

Comment: If I give line-height as 1.2, it seems to be working as expected in IE and FF both. Just wanted to know how normal works

Comment: 1.2 and 1.8 are the safest options to go with! (: